# How to disable pointers in pie chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

Pie Chart in highcharts, How to disable the line pointing outside pie-chart

[image]

pie chart example

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2
        }]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/)

Comment: your question will need serious rewrite to be understood

Comment: @Les In the image give above , I dont need the arrow marks pointing outside the pie chart.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) you can find the answer to your question, specifically you want [plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.connectorWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.connectorWidth).

There is even a pre made example there for exactly what you are asking: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-connectorwidth-disabled/).
Where they have added `connectorWidth: 0`

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        dataLabels: {
            connectorWidth: 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked, but I dont need even the comments on the side, I need it inside the pie chart

Comment: If you want to have the datalabels inside the pie points you can customize their position by using the distance feature, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9bojmaqp/1/

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to disable the label. check settings below:

```
     plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    format: '{point.name}: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Or in order to achieve no connectors use code below. **distance:0** will solve the purpose

```
<pre>
 plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
             distance:0,
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```